# Power source is shorting with stepper drivers

Tags: power-supply, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I’m having an issue with my TB6600 stepper motor driver and I’m hoping someone can help me out. I am currently running 3 steppers, each being fed 24 volts from the power supply. The first 2 work perfectly, but the third one only spins for about half a second.

Im running the configuration where all the DIR-, and PUL- (aka step-) are all tied to my arudino ground, which is not tied to power ground.

The first stepper motor is running a NEMA 23, with correct dipstick settings. The second is running a NEMA 17, also with correct dipstick settings. The third is also another NEMA 17, with the same dipstick settings as before.

When I run all three at the same time, somehow the Vcc and GND on the power source short according to a multimeter. There are no sparks or smoke and in fact, the first two work as normal. The power stays shorted for a minute after power gets cut.

Im almost certain this issue is different than similar questions posted. Others have said that the driver is drawing too much current and is stopping to protect itself. But this doesnt explain the power shorting. Also, if i were on wrong microstepping or current settings then the same result would show on the other nema 17 that im running, but again, the other motors work as intended.

I’ve tried changing the driver in case it was faulty, but no luck. I unplugged the 3rd driver and ran the other 2 and they still work, but this time there is no short on the power. I’ve tried multiple motors so it’s not the motor either and yes, my motors are also connected properly.

Should I try connecting my controller ground to the power ground?
I was also considering tieing power GND to the internal arduino GND, which is same thing but. BTW, voltage between arduino GND and power GND is in the mV range, so is the voltage between the arudino GND and the power Live. which i though was odd since the POWER GND and POWER Live are 24 volts at input of all drivers

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Datasheet Link:
(https://www.makerguides.com/wp content/uploads/2019/10/TB6600-Manual.pdf)

Sorry for poor english #engineer

[image: High level power connections]

[image: Low level schematic for how each stepper driver is setup]

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, please don't shout in the title, provide the schematics and possibly a wiring diagram. It is unclear how you connected the grounds.

Comment: If there is no direct ground connection between the two, then that is a problem.  It may not be the only problem though.  Diagrams will help you a lot in getting help here.

Comment: @Justme sorry, The schematic is in the datasheet.

Comment: the link does not go to a datasheet

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "power shorting"?  How is it still shorting after cutting power?

Comment: Okay, so I've learned that it may not have actually been shorting. I was thinking there was a short because I measured continuity with my multimeter, but apparently, the multimeter reads continous if the input current is equal to the output current, and it could have read continuously since the charging caps or somthing. Im really not sure. @jsotola  I have updated the post

Comment: Have you tried supplying the enable? Could be that one of the 3 disabled itself just because that had been floating.